# How do I create a Range class programatically in my google spreadsheet script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have this google script that I want to use to create charts in my spreadsheet. I'm basically programatically creating content (with the use of spreadsheet data) that I then want to plot. The way I used to do it is by filling one of the sheets with all the data and then using that data to plot, but I was hoping to skip that step and feed the javascript arrays directly into my addRange method.

So I've got a script that creates a new chart:

```js
  // insert the scenario chart
  var scenarioChartBuilder = sheet.newChart();
  scenarioChartBuilder.setPosition(5, 6, 5, 5)
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.AREA)
    .addRange(rangeObject);
  sheet.insertChart(scenarioChartBuilder.build());
```

The problem is; how do I make "rangeObject", given that I only have javascript arrays, and don't want to use actual spreadsheet data? Or is there another way of plotting data that isn't actually in a spreadsheet?

Comment: If you feel Tim answer is helps then you have to accept it. It will be useful to feature googlers. [How to accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Range data is actually just a multidimensional array.
So a rangeObject could just be defined like;

> var rangeobject = [[data, data, data],[data, data, data]];

The first array represents the row and the second array the column data.
programmatically you could get the data like;

> var dataFirstRowSecondColumn = rangedata[0][1]; //0 indexed array!

So, to add a range is just to pass a multidimensional array (with content data).
But beware ;-) When adding to a chart i would think that you would have to mind that each column would only contain on kind of data to be valid.

In code you could directly use my first example.